# How can I get spammy ssh "Starting Session" messages out of my syslog view?

Tags: 15.04, ssh, openssh, syslog

When I was running 14.04, I could use my Mac to run `ssh andy@eeePC8G.local 'tail /var/log/syslog'` and see the tail of syslog. I had GeekTool on the Mac setup to run this command frequently and display the results on my desktop. All was well; the tail of the Ubuntu machine's syslog would appear on the Mac's desktop.

I just formatted the 14.04 disk and installed 15.04 (using the old /home/ folder stored on a different disk). Now, when I run the same `ssh`+`tail` command on my Mac, it adds two lines to the syslog:

```
Oct 11 14:24:15 eeePC8G systemd[1]: Started Session 410 of user andy.
Oct 11 14:24:15 eeePC8G systemd[1]: Starting Session 410 of user andy.
```

That's fine, but when GeekTool is using this command to update every few seconds…

```
Oct 11 14:24:19 eeePC8G systemd[1]: Started Session 411 of user andy.
Oct 11 14:24:19 eeePC8G systemd[1]: Starting Session 411 of user andy.
Oct 11 14:24:25 eeePC8G systemd[1]: Started Session 412 of user andy.
Oct 11 14:24:25 eeePC8G systemd[1]: Starting Session 412 of user andy.
Oct 11 14:24:29 eeePC8G systemd[1]: Started Session 413 of user andy.
Oct 11 14:24:29 eeePC8G systemd[1]: Starting Session 413 of user andy.
Oct 11 14:24:34 eeePC8G systemd[1]: Started Session 414 of user andy.
Oct 11 14:24:34 eeePC8G systemd[1]: Starting Session 414 of user andy.
```

…all I can see now are messages letting me know I've connected to check the contents of syslog again. This makes the whole thing useless, as any important messages just scroll by in a matter of seconds.

Can I stop these messages from appearing in `/var/log/syslog`? Can I redirect this output to a different file other than syslog? How? Google and I have been trying and failing for more than an hour now. :/

Comment: This message is not coming from `openssh` (I didn't found it in sources and not even in git history). I can't find this message even in my Fedora logs (which I have running currently running), so it looks like some Ubuntu integration feature.

Comment: Unless I'm reading those log lines incorrectly, it seems clear that it's coming from `systemd`. SSH connections seem to be triggering systemd to post that message, since it happens when I use that ssh command. If I set the command for every 8 seconds, the messages are all exactly 8 seconds apart. If I stop the command from running, the messages in syslog stop immediately and don't happen again until I connect via ssh again.

Comment: Why not configure syslog to send the messages directly to your Mac? If that solution works for you, I can post the configuration as an answer.

Comment: @TomDamon That could work… I'd appreciate seeing what you have in mind, because I haven't made any progress on this yet :D

Comment: Was the answer I posted below helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the logs from your client directly to the Mac, log into the rsyslog client host sending the logs and create a /etc/rsyslog.d/loghost.conf file with the following line. Replace loghost in the example with a resolvable hostname or IP address of remote logging server.

```
*.* @@loghost:514
```

Here is a breakdown of the above remote logging syntax:

```
*.* - Matches all logging facilities and priorities.
@@ - Specifies that TCP is used for transferring the logs while a single @ will use UDP.
localhost - A resolvable hostname or IP address of the destination log host.
514 - The TCP port of the destination log host.
```

The following example will send only authentication entries and mail errors to the remote logging server.

```
authpriv.* @@loghost:514
mail.err   @@loghost:514
```

Restart the rsyslog service to begin sending the logs the remote host.

```
service rsyslog restart
```

I'm not familiar with the Mac OS, but [this site](https://meinit.nl/enable-an-apple-mac-os-x-machine-as-a-syslog-server) looks like it has the configuration information to set it up to receive logs.

The benefit of this is that you can collect logs from all of your devices in one place, so if you have routers or switched, you can send them straight to your Mac as well.

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure this out on the OS X side, and most of the information related to setting this up seems to be outdated for recent changes in OS X (El Cap). For example, the page you linked wants me to edit a file that is now uneditable under SIP/rootless. ...and I *could* disable SIP and edit it, but I'm not willing to do that yet. One of the comments suggests syslog-ng via Homebrew is easier, but that too is outdated and won't install. Thanks for trying! For now, I have GeekTool running `ssh andy@eeePC8G.local 'grep -v '\''Started Session'\'' /var/log/syslog | tail'`